# How to change the header and footer of the comint/compilation-mode?

Tags: comint, compilation-mode

I have a program `~/path/to/program.py`. In `program.py` I run `compile` (I usually do this with the second arg `COMINT=t`). I get,

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/path/to/" -*-
Comint started at Fri Apr  1 18:54:04

python3 program.py
Hello emacs stackexchange.

Comint finished at Fri Apr  1 18:54:04
```

I usually don't care for this header and footer information. Honestly, I'd love it if it would rather just show the execution time in the footer and leave the header alone. Consider,

```
python3 program.py
Hello emacs stackexchange.

Ran for 0.1 seconds.
```

**EDIT**

I took a look at [compilation-handle-exit](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/864c8013fdd0a548d98d81dd21af2f88f207858a/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L2343) and [compilation-start](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/864c8013fdd0a548d98d81dd21af2f88f207858a/lisp/progmodes/compile.el#L1761). These are rather long and hefty functions! The latter is 247 lines. Anyways, I see how I could achieve what I want but I am not really comfortable changing source within these or copying such huge functions in my configurations file and making  changes there. Is the only way to acheive what I want by altering source in these functions?

Comment: Have a look at `compilation-start` and `compilation-handle-exit`.  You can create new functions with the same names and modify them as you see fit.  You may need to load the `compile` library before redefining those functions -- I don't know if it loads by default when Emacs starts.

Comment: Still, you might wanna keep `-*- mode: compilation` for major mode.

Comment: What will happen otherwise?

Comment: @lawlist could you take a look at the edit?

Comment: In this particular case, the functions at issue are using the command `insert` to modify the buffer.  Modifying the functions `compilation-start` and `compilation-handle-exit` appears to be the only viable option -- without doing something crazy like temporarily modifying the behavior `insert`, which would be ill-advised to attempt.  The situation would be different if we just needed to intercept what happens before the functions are called, or intercept what happens immediately after the functions are called.

Comment: Since the inserts seem somewhat independent of the rest of the functions in question, do you think it makes sense to open a feature/bug report with Emacs repo? I think a better way to handle this would be to add two new functions which by default insert the texted that is inserted right now. But--in this manner, the user can change those default functions without having to change the start and exist functions themselves.

Comment: Feature requests and/or bug reports involve an investment of time, explaining and clarifying to the developers why that feature is helpful to the Emacs community and/or how to reproduce a particular bug.  It is usually never as simple as firing off just one email, and often times it may take a substantial amount of time for a developer who is interested in that aspect to take action or make a decision to close the report with no changes.  If you believe you can make the case that this benefits others, that would help; e.g., other threads on S.E. and/or S.O. and/or reddit about this same issue.